# Word to PDF to Notes Document using the POI4Xpages api

Tags: java, apache-poi, xpages, lotus-notes, ssjs

I have created a PDF from a word document using POI4XPages api.
here is the code:

```
var template = poiBean.buildResourceTemplateSource(null,"purchaseorder.docx");
var result = poiBean.processDocument2Stream(template, lst);
var is:java.io.InputStream = new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(result.toByteArray());
var os:java.io.OutputStream = poiBean.buildPDFFromDocX(is)
```

As you can see the result of my code is an OutputStream, The next step for me is to convert the stream to an attachment and attach it to a notesdocument but don't know how to do that.  It doesn't really matter if I first need to attach it to disc or if it written to a body field immediately.

The poiBean is described here
https://github.com/OpenNTF/POI4Xpages/blob/master/biz.webgate.dominoext.poi/src/biz/webgate/dominoext/poi/beans/PoiBean.java

I am using SSJS here but I guess a java solution would work as well.

thanks

Thomas

Answer (score 1):

Some copying and pasting but this is how you stream it into an richtext field but you need to convert os to an inputstream and assign this to a variable called is2

```
var stream:NotesStream = session.createStream();
session.setConvertMIME(false);
var doc:NotesDocument = database.createDocument();
var body:NotesMIMEEntity = doc.createMIMEEntity();
stream.setContents(is2); // is an inputstream
body.setContentFromBytes(stream, "application/octet-stream",NotesMIMEEntity.ENC_IDENTITY_BINARY);

stream.close();
doc.save(true, true);

session.setConvertMIME(true);
```

This is what I based the example on

https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=create-html-mails-in-ssjs-using-mime

Comment: yes, I've used something like that, but the problem is that setContent takes inputStream and I have outputStream.

Comment: @Thomas Adrian: "takes inputStream and I have outputStream": If the outputStream writes to a file, then take the file after that using an FileInputStream. If the outputStream writes to a byte array, then take the byte array after that using an ByteArrayInputStream. If the outputStream writes to a foo, then take the foo after that using an FooInputStream. Any questions?